# SQL COUNT WITH CONDITION OF NOT COUNTING SAME RECORD

Tags: sql

I want to ask about SQL query where I can exclude the other same record on my counting query

```
select count(Number) 
from [LBC.BIOS].[lbcbios].[Request] 
where Number
```

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: You can use DISTINCT keyword if you are trying to find count of unique "Number" as 

select count(DISTINCT Number)  from [LBC.BIOS].[lbcbios].[Request]

Comment: i have many save on my db table but there's no expected keyword all i want i to count the record in 1 column but exclude the same record

Comment: i have many save on my db table but there's no expected keyword all i want i to count the record in 1 column but exclude the same record

Comment: up please helpp